# Complexity of pandas.apply() with lambda

Tags: python, pandas, performance, lambda, time-complexity

Hello I'd like to know how this code is on complexity notation big O, `df1` has ``N rows and `df2` has M rows, `M << N`.
Evry `x` in `var_ref` will be searched in set(df2.var0). does this equal to `N*N == O(n^2)` ??

```
df1['var1'] = df1['var_ref'].apply(lambda x: True if x in df2.var0.unique() else False) * 1
```

Comment: Searching in set is constant, so this should be O(MN). Since you mentioned M<<N, so it's kind of still O(N). If you save your unique set somewhere first and then call that directly, then it will  be O(N) for sure (so that you don't need to do `var.unique()` every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be O(N * M). With M the number of unique in df2.

And you should save the unique list somewhere to not calculate it each time.

```
u = df2.var0.unique()
df1['var1'] = df1['var_ref'].apply(lambda x: True if x in u else False) * 1
```

I pass from 159 ms to 5 ms (600 rows)

Comment: Why when I save it as `u = df2.var.unique()` it take more time than when I save it as `set(df2.var)`??

Comment: Iterations over `set` might be faster than on `numpy.ndarray` ....
On which size of dataset did you make this comparaison ?

Comment: My N is about 1million fows, M when is set() is 40K. It was very fast about 5s!!

Comment: When I use set() it’s very fast but when ndarray it take minutes. Thanks

Comment: `0.24 seconds` when using set()
`454.08 seconds` when using pd.col.unique().
Output is same results
How this difference is explainable?

Comment: `pd.col.unique()` is called at each apply on each row, so it recompute the uniques values. If I recall well `set` use hashmap for search so it's O(1) complexity, on the other half a numpy array will be iterated to find the value.

Comment: Yeah, with set, this should be `O(N)`, not `O(N * M)`. With a list, this would be `O(NM)`.